# Flutter DateTime parsing

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I want to add offset GMT +05:30 to Time but I don't know how to do that

```
String offset = data ['utc_offset'].substring(1,);

ntime =ntime.add(Duration(hours:int.parse(offset)));
```

Since there is " **:** " in the middle of 05:30 I can't add the exact value..

PS: I'm using http://worldtimeapi.org JSON API

Comment: Please add full code. What is ntime? add data example

Comment: @KirillMatrosov it's just a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the offset time by using a RegExp. I have used named groups in my example since I finds it more simple to understand what each part of the regexp are extracting:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  const offset = '+01:00';
  final regexp =
      RegExp(r'^(?<plusMinus>[+-]?)(?<hours>[\d]+):(?<minutes>[\d]+)');
  final match = regexp.firstMatch(offset);

  print(match.namedGroup('plusMinus'));
  print(match.namedGroup('hours'));
  print(match.namedGroup('minutes'));

  final offsetDuration = Duration(
      hours: int.parse(match.namedGroup('hours')),
      minutes: int.parse(match.namedGroup('minutes')));

  DateTime time;
  if (match.namedGroup('plusMinus') == '+') {
    time = DateTime.now().add(offsetDuration);
  } else if (match.namedGroup('plusMinus') == '-') {
    time = DateTime.now().subtract(offsetDuration);
  } else {
    time = DateTime.now();
  }

  print(time);
}
```