# Dart DateTime how to retain time zone offset information

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

Dart DateTime doesn't keep the time zone offset and timezone package isn't much of a help. I've read through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619349/dart-datetime-parse-timezoneoffset-is-always-0/65619531#65619531) but it doesn't answer my question.

What should I do if I receive a DateTime including time zone offset and I need to check if the timezone offset is matching the local timezone offset and show warning if not?

Comment: Use the [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) api present in the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package for parse and checks.

Comment: DateFormat is limited to local and UTC options the same way DateTime is.

Comment: @TadashiCZ so how did you solve this? I found only  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062250/flutter-datetime-parsing to parse (and retain) offset separately, and no one out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Really wish Dart team provided a package or class to keep track of the offsets. I would think that it's a fairly common case to want to display information based on an offset/timezone. I've searched and I feel like the best thing is to just roll with my own solution.